# Identical tables, different sizes?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, storage, replication, sql-server-express

I have transactional replication with updatable subscriptions going between a few SQL 2008 R2 servers (publisher is Enterprise, subscribers are Express).

I need to add another subscriber, and come to discover that my database has outgrown the 10GB limit for Express. My current subscribers are under the 10GB limit, however the publishing database is 13GB.

So I delete some large unused columns and data from the largest tables, run dbcc cleantable, run update statistics on them, the tables go down in size a bit and I thought I was good to go!

However, the publishing database is still a good 11.5GB while the subscribers all went down to 8GB.

I compare table sizes between the publishers and subscribers and the few largest tables that I had deleted data from are larger in the publishing database than the subscribing databases - by a couple gigs.

I compare table structures and use RedGate's Data Compare - the tables are identical between the publisher and subscribers so I am at a loss. I don't know what is cause the discrepancy let alone how to resolve it so I can add another subscriber (without having to buy SQL Standard licenses for the subscriber). I have a feeling it has to do with being the publisher and it's row-count has grown significantly within the last year.

As a side note - I do also have a couple SQL Standard 2008 licenses, however they're 2008, not 2008 R2 therefore incompatible to initialize the subscriber using a backup. The sites have slow connections so I have always initialized replication from backups.

Comment: I have no idea, but you might find better answers on http://serverfault.com. It's dedicated to such questions.

Comment: Alrighty, trying there as well! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would it be possible to drop the replication and recreate it? Replication always seems to be finicky and it might still have remnants of the columns out there (where you can't see it)

Remember you can script the rep so you don't have to start from scratch.

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what I'm going to have to do. In desperation, I made a copy the table on the publisher and voila! the table size cut itself in half. So I will have to disable replication for that table, switch out the tables, and re-enable replication on it. Thank you!

Comment: Ok but now I have another problem - the primary key on it is an identity column! That other tables already are referencing, so I can't just let the system reseed the entire table! How would I get an identical copy of the table with the identity column intact?

Comment: I believe you can set the identity column on the source as identity not for replication. Or on the destination make it NOT an identity column and the values will be carried over.

Comment: Correct, my copies of the tables' identity values carried over, but it will not let me update the column to identity.. when I copied the tables, the other column properties carried over except for that one. And I need the column to be identity because it needs to increment for new records. Hmm

Comment: So are you adding records on both systems and putting it over on system b? Your going to have records on B that are from A and B?If so you can't use the same identity because you'll have record 12 from A and record 12 from B and the system won't let you do that.

Comment: Solved it (sort of). Restarted the SQL Server and the tables shrunk themselves strangely enough. I should have remembered the technical help motto - "Have you tried restarting?"